# Can i use an actual network management application and connect it to a router inside GNS3?

Tags: router, linux, gns3, virtual, nms

I want to connect a NMS to a router on GNS if it's possible, so that i can practice the "actual thing".

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have connectivity between your GNS3 and your LAN, this is going to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As Samirtow mentioned, as long as there is connectivity between NMS and Cisco, there shoudn't be any problem. Some time ago I tested some management software ([sshdm](https://sshdm.net)) in GNS on my laptop. For some reason I didn't have connectivity between my laptop and the CISCO router in GNS, had no ping, using LAN interface. My guess it because the LAN interface was'n connected, the status of the interface was unplugged. So if that is you case, you could either connect it via any interface that is plugged-in, or create a windows loopback adapter. There is a guide here: http://www.smartpctricks.com/2014/06/connecting-gns3-real-networks.html.